# LMM and RM-ANOVA differences. Which one is preferable?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I conducted a four-phases experiment in which data from two groups of subjects are extracted
for each time point according to the states of the outcome variable `Dur`. So, this variable can be basically decomposed into four states. What I would like to see is if the two groups have different values of the dependent variable for each state.
The raw data looks like the following table:

[image]

I then subsetted the data into four dataframe according to the phase of the experiment, and performed a linear mixed model for the single phases, like this:

```
1_data <- subset(df2, phase == "1")
2_data <- subset(df2, phase == "2")
3_data <- subset(df2, phase == "3")
4_data <- subset(df2, phase == "4")

model <- lmer(Dur ~ 1 + Group* state + (1|id), data = 1_data )
model <- lmer(Dur ~ 1 + Group* state + (1|id), data = 2_data )
model <- lmer(Dur ~ 1 + Group* state + (1|id), data = 3_data )
model <- lmer(Dur ~ 1 + Group* state + (1|id), data = 4_data )
```

Subsequently, I looked at the single contrasts, binding all of them in one table and applying the FDR and Bonferroni correction for multiple comparisons.

However, the model gives me the following warning:
`boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')`

I've read other related answers that say that this is occurring because the random effect specification is too complex. Anyway, I cannot simplify further the model.

So, my idea was instead to conduct a RM-ANOVA and then performing a post-hoc test by means of unpaired t-test.

```
> res.aov <- anova_test(data = baseline_data, dv = dur, wid = id, between = Group, within = state)
> get_anova_table(res.aov)
ANOVA Table (type III tests)

              Effect  DFn    DFd     F     p    p<.05     ges
1            Group     1.00  40.00 0.130 0.720       0.000123
2            state     2.87 114.97 5.617 0.001     * 0.119000
3     Subject:state    2.87 114.97 2.956 0.037     * 0.066000
```

Would that be better? Or, in this case, would be just the same thing as LMM? As I already confronted the results of `anova(model)` with that `res.aov`, they are quite similar but not the same.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use neither.

1. I don't understand why you fit separate models instead of including the phase in the model.
2. Your dependent variable looks like you should be using a GLMM with a different distribution family than the normal distribution. Your data might even be zero-inflated?
3. You can get this warning if the variance of the random effect is basically zero. In such a case you might need to specify different starting values for the optimizer or use a fixed-effects model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75831110/1412059

Comment: 1. I choose to fit separate models instead of including the phase ( it should be `model<-lmer( Dur ~ 1 + Group*state*phase +(1|id) , data = data)` ??) because I am mainly interested in calculating simple contrasts only for each state between the two groups. Otherwise, I will generate more contrasts than necessary. However, I am not aware of other possible strategies at the moment.  2. Yes, the data contains a lot of zeros. In my case, that would mean that the state is not present. 3. Indeed, the conditional R2 is zero. But the same warning occurs even when I include the phase in the model.

Comment: The second issue should be solved first. Look into hurdle models and similar approaches.

Comment: I solved this issue, handling zeros as missing data. That would be the correct way in this field of study. By the way, I also checked the normality of the data and I might be use a non-parametric model, which for RM-ANOVA would be a Friedman test, though it is a one-way test. I don't know what else I can apply